Select the maximum voltage from 2 synchronized alternating current sources
I have two phase-synchronized AC circuits, A and B, derived from a single master AC source. Depending on the state of a switch in the system one of the circuits will be 120 volts while the other will be ~10 volts. At any point in time these voltages could be reversed (i.e. circuit A is 120V and circuit B is 10V, or circuit A is 10V and circuit B is 120V). How could I combine these two circuits so that I always have the maximum 120V output?

1st define transition specifications and  Load Z(f) {a priori} then purpose

Is this a homework question?

As with all questions, you should show clearly at least some of your own working. What do you understand about this? What bits specifically do you need help with?

Here's one way

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

... assuming you don't care about the phase reversal when they switch.
